# Add user input for Python/Twitter Api script

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

I am looking for a way to update my Tweeply API request in Python, to allow users to input a location and date to be able to search from.

I currently have a sentimental analysis tool built, which currently lets users input a search term, and no. of tweets to able to search from.

I am looking for a way for this to be updated so the API request looks for user location, and also a date for when the tweets were published (I'm aware you can only go back 7 days with the Twitter API)

This is how my code looks currently:

```
searchTerm = input("Enter Keyword/Tag to search about: ")
NoOfTerms = int(input("Enter how many tweets to search: "))
self.tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerm, lang="en").items(NoOfTerms)
```